# pandoc lua filter to apply Emphasis character style to Emph elements when converting to docx

Tags: filter, lua, pandoc

I'm using pandoc to convert from latex to docx. In the pandoc AST, emphasized text is marked with "Emph", like this:

```
, Emph [ Str "Variety" ]
```

and is rendered as italics when writing out to the docx file. I would like to use a lua filter to apply Emphasis character style defined in the reference docx file to such text. I have read all the documentation but still lack the necessary info and skill to write the filter myself. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by changing the `Emph` into a `Span` with a `custom-style` attribute:

```lua
function Emph (emph)
  return pandoc.Span(emph.content, {['custom-style'] = 'Emphasis'})
end
```